# Inheritance in Segue

Tags: ios, xcode, class, inheritance, segue

I Have 4 View Controllers. A , B, C, D with Segues between them
A- Shows Levels to chose from(1-4) 
B- Level 1 Question 1 (View Controller loops until all questions from Plist have been displayed)
C- If user gets question1 wrong perform incorrect Segue using the

```
[performSegueWithIdentifier:@"wrongAnswer"sender:nil];
```

D- If level is complete(all questions have been displayed and answered correctly) perform segue

```
[performSegueWithIdentifier:@"wrongAnswer"sender:nil];
```

A VC has its own class- levels class
B- has its own class -Level1Addition class
C-subclass of Level1Addition class as B is passing data to C.
D is performed when all questions have been displayed. When all questions have been displayed I want to go back to View Controller A and chose the next level. I seem to be having a problem with inheritance. What class should D derive from or should I create a brand new one for D.

Comment: Say what?? A clearer explanation (perhaps with some punctuation) of what you're trying to do would help.

Comment: Hope this makes it easier

Answer (score 0):

Use below method while performing segue to check conditions

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"identifierName"]) {
        //data to pass to next VC or other before performing segue
        secondVC = [segue destinationViewController];

    }
}
```